# Wordpress add_image_size maximum height/width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the following Wordpress function to create a new image size:

```
add_image_size('image-custom', 500, 9999);
```

I have a rather unusual situation that I need to resize the image so that the maximum side (height or width) is 500px. Is this possible or do I need to create two image sizes and use logic when to display which image?

Comment: Just to clarify, the image input may be 450 x 9999 but the width needs to be 500 always?

Comment: @ham-sandwich Sort of, whichever is greater (the width or the height) needs to be 500. If an image is 1000x500 it would be resized to 500x250. But 500x1000 would be resized to 250x500. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, last clarification question from me - is this for retina display purposes?

Comment: @ham-sandwich No, it's for use in a photo gallery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set dimensions with the last parameter set to false, Wordpress does not crop the image, it resizes it proportionally within the limits set for width and height, which means that

add_image_size ( 'image-custom', 500 , 500 , false ) ;

will achieve exactly what you want : 
- landscape image will have a width of 500 and a height lower than 500, proportions kept
- portrait images will have a height of 500 and a width lower than 500

Comment: "false" is the default value of the last parameter, so you can also write it this way: add_image_size('image-custom', 500, 500);

Answer (score 2):

### With CSS:

I would register one size only with large enough proportions so that it works for both landscape and portrait, and use `max-height` and `max-width` CSS properties:

```
.gallery img {
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

That way, the image will maintain its aspect ratio and adjust based on which dimension is larger: height or width.

### With PHP (untested):

Assuming it's a WP gallery you are talking about:

```
/* In functions.php */
add_image_size('custom-portrait', 500, 9999, true);
add_image_size('custom-landscape', 9999, 500, true);

/* Inside the loop */
if ( get_post_gallery(get_the_ID(), false) ) {
    foreach( get_post_gallery(get_the_ID(), false)['ids'] as $id ) {
        $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
        echo $meta['height'] > $meta['width'] ? get_the_post_thumbnail('custom-portrait') : get_the_post_thumbnail('custom-landscape');
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use this method as it will be downloading images that are much larger than required and therefore increase the page loading time.

Comment: Then the only alternative would be to register two different sizes, and accessing image dimensions on the PHP side to see which image size to echo.

Comment: I just updated my answer to provide a PHP approach to your problem.